# Get elements form list based on content of each element of list

Tags: python

I'm just starting to learn and faced one problem in Python.

I have a srt doc (subtitles). Name - sub. It looks like:

```
8
00:01:03,090 --> 00:01:05,260
<b><font color="#008080">MATER:</font></b> Yes, sir, you did.
<b><font color="#808000">(MCQUEEN GASPS)</font></b>

9
00:01:05,290 --> 00:01:07,230
You used to say
that all the time.
```

In Python it looks like:

```
'3', '00:00:46,570 --> 00:00:48,670', '<b><font color="#008080">MCQUEEN:</font></b> Okay, here we go.', '', '4', '00:00:48,710 --> 00:00:52,280', 'Focus. Speed. I am speed.', '', '5', '00:00:52,310 --> 00:00:54,250', '<b><font color="#808000">(ENGINES ROARING)</font></b>', '',
```

Also, I had a list of words (name - noun). It looks like:

```
['man', 'poster', 'motivation', 'son' ... 'boy']
```

Let's look at this example:

```
...'4', '00:00:48,710 --> 00:00:52,280', 'Focus. Speed. I am speed.', '', '5',....
```

What I need to do is to find word from the list in the subtitles (first apperrence, as an illustrtion, "Speed") and get into list the time of the word appearence (00:00:48,710 --> 00:00:52,280) and sequence number (4), which is located before the time in the document. I was trying to get this information with indx but unfortunately I did not succeed.

Can you help me how to do this?)

Comment: How are you getting that subtitle doc into Python? It would make sense to split the list on each new entry during import. Trying to find the matching data afterwards is cumbersome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing with **Anton vBR**'s suggestion:

```
words=['ingonyama','king']
results=[]
for w in words:
    for row in df.itertuples():
        if row[2] is not None:
            if w in row[2].lower():
                results.append((w, row[0], row[1]))
        if row[3] is not None:
            if w in row[3].lower():
                results.append((w, row[0], row[1]))
print(results)
```

You'll get a list of tuples, each of which contains a word you're searching for, a sequence number where it appears, and a time-frame where it appears. Then you can write these tuples to a csv file or whatever. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO and Python. Although this is not an answer I think it might be helpful. The one and only Python library for tables is Pandas. You can read in the srt file to a dataframe and work your way from there. (You would need to learn the Pandas syntax do to stuff but it is well-invested time)

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

# Lion King subtitle
data = requests.get("https://opensubtitles.co/download/67071").text

df = pd.DataFrame([i.split("\r\n") for i in data.split("\r\n\r\n")])
df = df.rename(columns={0:"Index",1:"Time",2:"Row1",3:"Row2"}).set_index("Index")
```

Printing first 5 rows `print(df.head())` gives:

```
                                Time                          Row1  Row2
Index                                                                   
1      00:01:01,600 --> 00:01:05,800        <i>Nants ingonyama</i>  None
2      00:01:05,900 --> 00:01:07,200           <i>Bagithi baba</i>  None
3      00:01:07,300 --> 00:01:10,600  <i>Sithi uhhmm ingonyama</i>  None
4      00:01:10,700 --> 00:01:13,300              <i>lngonyama</i>  None
5      00:01:13,300 --> 00:01:16,400        <i>Nants ingonyama</i>  None
```